# How to get inet in entity class in spring using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

```
public List getAllEmployees() 
{
    return sessionFactory.openSession().createSQLQuery("select * from employee order by eid").list();
}
```

employee table has a column `ipadres`,type is `inet` in postgresql.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name="eid")
    private int eid;
    private int dept_id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String project;
    private String password;
    @Column(name="ipadres")
    private String ipadres;
    private double salary;
    private Date Doj;
```

This is my pojo class. I have  taken `ipadres` as string,but it gives me following exception.

> org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was faced with similar problem when i had to create a custom Money type.

The solution is to create your own class which implements the `UserType` interface.

Here is a great article regarding the matter: [example](http://blog.xebia.com/understanding-and-writing-hibernate-user-types/)

In a nuthshell you are interested in implementing the following mehods:

```
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

public InetType impelements UserType{

public Class<String> returnedClass() {
    return String.class;
}

public int[] sqlTypes() {
    return new int[] { Types.OTHER }; // as the db type is inet and not directly transmutable to hibernate type.
}

public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, Object owner)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    String value = (String) Hibernate.STRING.nullSafeGet(resultSet, names[0]);
    return value;        
}

public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object value, int index)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    Hibernate.STRING.nullSafeSet(preparedStatement, 
            (value != null) ? value.toString() : null, index);
}
}
```

Then in your Employee entity, you need to add type definition annotations:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
@TypeDefs(value={@TypeDef(name="inetType",typeClass=InetType.class)})
public class Employee {

    @Column(name="ipadres")
    @Type(type="inetType")
    private String ipadres;
```

Comment: Thanks bro!!! I have  seen a similar solution,was looking for a simple one..nvm thanks a ton  @Maciej Kowalski

Comment: Glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer of Maciej, that is correct, add:

In versions of hibernate 4+ the methods **nullSafeGet** and **nullSafeSet** will be:

```
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    final String value =  (String) StandardBasicTypes.STRING.nullSafeGet(rs, names, session, owner);
    return value;       
}

    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement ps, Object value, int index, 
SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
         StandardBasicTypes.STRING.nullSafeSet(ps, (value != null) ? 
value.toString(): null, index, session);
}
```

Also say that you can define the type in the **package-info.java** like

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef(name = "inetType", typeClass = InetType.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

After few days research, I find out no need to reinvent the wheel in 2022.

There is a lib [vladmihalcea/hibernate-types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) implement `Inet column type` & `Inet Hibernate Type`.

#### resource

mvn repos: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.vladmihalcea

tutorial: https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-inet-type-hibernate/

GitHub: https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types

#### Example from [tutorial](https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-inet-type-hibernate/)

```
@Entity(name = "Event")
@Table(name = "event")
@TypeDef(
    name = "ipv4",
    typeClass = PostgreSQLInetType.class,
    defaultForType = Inet.class
)

public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    @Column(
        name = "ip",
        columnDefinition = "inet"
    )
    private Inet ip;
 
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
 
    public Inet getIp() {
        return ip;
    }
 
    public void setIp(String address) {
        this.ip = new Inet(address);
    }
}
```

Work as expected in `spring-boot 2.7.1`, `hibernate 5.6.9`.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by poking around:

```sql
CREATE CAST (CHARACTER VARYING as inet) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;
```

And mark entity with

```kotlin
    @Column(columnDefinition = "inet")
    var ip: String? = null
```